# Comparing nested list Python

Tags: python, list, nested

I guess the code will most easily explain what I'm going for...

```
list1 = [("1", "Item 1"), ("2", "Item 2"), ("3", "Item 3"), ("4", "Item 4")]
list2 = [("1", "Item 1"), ("2", "Item 2"), ("4", "Item 4")]

newlist = []

for i,j in list1:
    if i not in list2[0]:
        entry = (i,j)
        newlist.append(entry)

print(newlist)
```

if we call the nested tuples [i][j]

I want to compare the [i] but once this has been done I want to keep the corresponding [j] value.

I have found lots of information regarding nested tuples on the internet but most refer to finding a specific item.

I did recently use an expression below, which worked perfectly, this seems very similar, but it just won't play ball.

```
for i,j in highscores:
    print("\tPlayer:\t", j, "\tScore: ", i)
```

Any help would be much apppreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't explain what you're going for :-).  What do you want to get out of this?

Comment: This has been hard to describe .... 

I want to compare the first of the nested sequence. 

i.e. I want it to notice that in list1: "3" doesn't appear. But I want the item nested with it to also be retained. 

In short I'd like newlist to contain [("3", "Item 3")]

Comment: I don't doubt that.  But if we can't tell what you're asking for, it's going to be hard to give you advice.  Let's start off easy.  Given `list1` and `list2` above, what would you like to be in `newlist` after everything is all finished?

Comment: sorry - i hit enter and didnt realise that would post not give a return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comment you would like to take as newlist:

```
newlist = [("3", "Item 3")]
```

You can do this using:

1) list comprehension:

```
newlist = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
print newlist
```

This will give you as a result:

```
[('3', 'Item 3')]
```

2) You could also use [symmetric difference](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/symmetric_difference.html) like:

```
L = set(list1).symmetric_difference(list2)
newlist = list(L)
print newlist
```

This will also give you the same result!

3) Finally you can use a lambda function like:

```
unique = lambda l1, l2: set(l1).difference(l2)
x = unique(list1, list2)
newlist = list(x)
```

This will also produce the same result!

4) Oh, and last but not least, using simple set properties:

```
newlist = list((set(list1)-set(list2)))
```

Comment: Wow! 

Yeah thats exactly right. That might take a while to get my head around. But works perfectly!

Comment: Can i ask why does 'item for item' get repeated at the beginning?

Comment: @Jup, Just updated the answer with a second way which may be a bit more easy ! Hope it will be of some help!

Comment: @Jup, The second item exists just to define that item refers to-is a member of list1 and It is just the way comprehension lists work (syntactically). There is a lot of staff in the internet about them and are a very interesting topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to create a set of the first elements of list2, if you're only looking to compare the first element of the lists.

```
newlist = []
list2_keys = set(elem[0] for elem in list2)
for entry in list1:
    if entry[0] not in list2_keys:
        newlist.append(entry)
```

Comment: The big difference between this and the previous answer is that this compares only the first elements of the tuples. The other answer compares the whole tuple.